# Change secure http page content in a Firefox extension using Greasemonkey compiler

Tags: javascript, firefox, https, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I'm building a Firefox extension that alters the page content of a few select websites and I'm using the Greasemonkey compiler to do this (http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/advanced/compiler.html).

The trouble I'm having though is with websites using secure http. Even if I list the https version of the site in my @includes, Greasemonkey still doesn't pick it up and change the scripted content.

Any ideas on how I can still have the same effect on https sites? Thanks.

Comment: GreaseMonkey doesn't seem to have any restrictions concerning https - but maybe that compiler does. Did you try the regular GreaseMonkey? **Edit**: The script compiler under http://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler doesn't seem to have any such restrictions either.

Comment: Does a plain Greasemonkey script work?  Odds are that something else is going on (iFrames, Ajaxed content, etc.).